# Azure DevOps Pipeline Copy Files Task Target Directory Value

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am new to Azure DevOps. I tried many ways but nothing helped. I am trying to create a pipeline which has Copy Files Task. I have folder structure like below

```
Bin
  Common
    abc.dll

Staging
  Bin
    Common
```

I want to copy abc.dll from Bin\Common to Staging\Bin\Common

In my Copy Files Task I am giving below

```
Source: Bin/Common
Contents: *.dll
Target Folder: Staging/Bin/Common

In Advanced:
Clean Target Folder: Check
Overwrite: Check
```

The Copy File Task succeeds and when I go to my Repo I donot see abc.dll in Staging\Bin\Common folder. In my Copy File Task log I see

```
Copying D:\a\1\s\Bin\Common\abc.dll to Staging\Bin\Common\abc.dll
```

I guess it must be

```
Copying D:\a\1\s\Bin\Common\abc.dll to D:\a\1\s\Staging\Bin\Common\abc.dll
```

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to `4c74356b41` for pointing me in right direction. I accepted and marked as answer. As suggested, I created variable and used it like below

```
Variable Name: BinCommonStagingFolder
Variable Value: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\Staging\Bin\Common\
```

I used the variable in my Copy Files Task like below to copy only files which I need not all files

```
Source: Bin/Common
Contents: 
abc.dll
abc.pdb
Target Folder: $(BinCommonStagingFolder)

In Advanced:
Clean Target Folder: Check
Overwrite: Check
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess you should add full path, you can use build varible for that:

```
Target Folder: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\Staging\Bin\Common\
```

this would reference the root of the repo you checked out

Comment: Wow you are awesome.. This solved my issue. Now I see Copying D:\a\1\s\Bin\Common\abc.dll to D:\a\1\s\Staging\Bin\Common\abc.dll and I see abc.dll in my Artifact.

Comment: Some how in Azure DevOps.. in my Repo.. under Staging\Bin\Common I donot see abc.dll but my artifact has it. Maybe after copy to Staging\Bin\Common I need to do any commit task

Comment: well, you need to commit the change to the repo, if you want it in the repo, but not sure why you would want build artifact in the repo

Comment: my scenario is.. in azure build solution...somehow store the libraries and pdb files in some folder.. copy libraries(dlls) and pdbs into staging folder.. then publish artifact that has this dlls so that we can deploy this to server

Comment: okay, but why do you need them in the repo, not in the build artifact?

Comment: I am new to this.. in my path to Publish Artifact ask I have Path to Publish property. I am giving my staging folder here.  so I want to build solution... somehow get dlls and pdbs to this staging folder...so I need a way to capture my dlls and pdbs which are result of my solution build...

Comment: you just said they are in the build artifacts

Comment: ok.. can you tell me the steps from build your solution and get your dlls and pdbs into artifact.. currently I am checking in my dlls and pdbs also...and these dlls and pdbs which I checked in are making into artifacts...by I want dlls and pdbs of those that are output of build of my solution in azure...

Comment: high level steps are: build, move to some place (or build to this place), publish artifacts

Comment: Thanks.. My understanding was wrong... In my Build Solution Task Log I see Copying file from "obj\Debug\abc.dll" to "..\Bin\Common\abc.dll" so what I get into Bin\Common is good... I am trying out few things to understand whats going on.. I will let you know...

Comment: Thank @4c74356b41 for helping to understand. Now I got what I want. I check in my solution... I donot check-in  my dlls and pdbs.. I copy my build output libraries and pdbs into staging folder and create an artifact which has my dlls and pdbs so that we can deploy this to server....

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was because I migrated from a Windows pipeline to a Linux one and path separators **"\"** on Windows hadn't been updated to **"/"** causing relative paths to be wrongly interpreted.